# PTIJ: Is a hot-dog a sandwich?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A neder is where one forbids oneself benefit from an object such as food.

There's a rule concerning nedarim that [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.30b.12):

> וּבִנְדָרִים הַלֵּךְ אַחַר לְשׁוֹן בְּנֵי אָדָם.
> with regard to vows, follow the colloquial language.

That being so, if one makes a neder not to have hanaah from a sandwich can he eat a hot dog bun? This is based off of the age-old debate of whether a hot dog is a sandwich or not.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid PTIJ question. Deciding how we evaluate modern language constructs for the purposes of interpreting nedarim is totally a real question. A PTIJ version would be something like can a hot dog be used for the Hillel Sandwich

Comment: @DoubleAA Funny you mention that. When I asked it as a real question, it was closed and I was told to come back now - Purim Torah

Comment: You were told by a single user to come back now, whilst many users thought it was just straight off topic https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137044/is-a-hot-dog-a-sandwich#comment456657_137044 I say this because others might think a mod closed your post with this recommendation and I'm going back on that. That's not the case.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Should I remove the ptij tag then? Is it therfore off-topic as before?

Comment: If he forbade himself benefit from a dog...

Answer (score 2):

Your question poses the situation where one has vowed not to enjoy a sandwich, but then asks if one can eat a hot dog bun.  It is a matter of considerable debate whether or not a hot dog is a sandwich. Luckily for you, this conundrum need not be answered at this moment. You are asking about eating a hot dog *bun*, which is unequivocally *not* a sandwich, any more than a slice of bread is. If no other substance is placed inside the hot dog bun, then it is not a sandwich and you may enjoy it without violating your neder.  Have fun!